# Excel VBA Labelling Data

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm currently trying to label data from a table. The table contains a column that gives a description of an event. Those descriptions have Keywords that could be used to label the event itself. So I just need to check which keyword each description contains to label it. Therefore, I tried to create a function with a simple ElseIf statement to check if the description contains a keyword like this:

```
Public Function Teste(ByVal Gasto As String) As String

' Atualizar Calc
Application.Volatile
    
If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("DULCE", Gasto)) <> True Then
    
    Teste = "RETIRADA DULCE"
    
ElseIf IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("SALARIO", Gasto)) <> True Then
    
    Teste = "FOLHA DE PAGAMENTO"
    
End If
End Function
```

Everything works well for the first condition, however, when the first condition is not found and we go to the second condition test it raises a value error. Could someone help me out with this one? Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the worksheet property:

```
Public Function Teste(ByVal Gasto As String) As String

' Atualizar Calc
Application.Volatile
    
If IsError(Application.Search("DULCE", Gasto)) <> True Then
    
    Teste = "RETIRADA DULCE"
    
ElseIf IsError(Application.Search("SALARIO", Gasto)) <> True Then
    
    Teste = "FOLHA DE PAGAMENTO"
    
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the InStr function:

```
Public Function Teste(ByVal Gasto As String) As String

' Atualizar Calc
Application.Volatile
    
If InStr(1, Gasto, "DULCE") > 0 Then
    Teste = "RETIRADA DULCE"
ElseIf InStr(1, Gasto, "SALARIO") > 0 Then
    Teste = "FOLHA DE PAGAMENTO"
    
End If
End Function
```